# problemas con la fecha actual al modificar un registro

Tags: python, django, django-models

necesito ayuda con el siguiente problema:

La pregunta fue actualizada!!!

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando voy a insertar el año en el field `Año` (actualmente estoy trabajando con la libreria datetimepicker la cual funciona perfectamente) la idea es que por defecto en el campo Año aparesca el año actual. Esto lo logro solucionar con el siguiente codigo de JavaScript:

```
 $('#anno').datetimepicker({    
        format: 'YYYY',
        //date: moment().format("YYYY"), //esta propiedad debe estar activa
        locale: 'es',
    });
```

El problema real es cuando intento modificar un registro existe, pues si la propiedad `date: moment().format("YYYY")` esta activa el registro a modificar va a tener el año actual y no el año del registro.

Cuando esa propiedad esta desactivada entonces en el caso de insertar no aparece ningun valor en el field (pero el datetimepicker tiene marcado el año actual) y en el caso de modificar pasa lo mismo (el datetimepicker tiene marcado el año del registro).

Necesito que cuando valla a insertar un registro aparesca por defecto el año actual, pero que cuando valla a actualizar un registro el valor que aparesca sea el del registro no el actual.

Adjunto el codigo de mi form:

```
class OcupacionForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tipoocupacion'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = True
           
    class Meta:
        model = OcupacionPortador
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'anno': TextInput(
                attrs={            
                    'autocomplete': 'off',
                    'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
                    'id': 'anno',
                    'data-target': '#anno',
                    'data-toggle': 'datetimepicker'
                }
            ),
            'tipoocupacion': Select(attrs={'class': 'select2', 'style': 'width: 100%'}),
            'mes': Select(attrs={'class': 'select2', 'style': 'width: 100%'}),
            'lectura': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ingrese una lectura',}),     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de tratar actualizar, ya que no quieres que se modifique, te recomendaría que hagas otro modelo de formulario en forms.py donde no contenga el año. Así tendrías para cargar al momento de crear, pero al actualizar no usaría la formula de tu models.py

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Habría que intentar esto que propones, sin embargo no lo veo factible, ya que en caso de que el registro que inserte si lo puse en el año incorrecto entonces cuando voy a modificar el año del registro ¿como lo modifico?